# How do i create an autofill prompt that displays the password?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Here is an example of my desired output. So far what I have is having the password hidden. It is possible for the prompt to be seen? I'm trying to work on a school project for this. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

[image]

Comment: Maybe use of Autocompletetextview is good

Answer (score 0):

[image: and you will have what in the attached image and when you click in this eye, the password will appear]You can do this :

```
         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```